# Errors using mdframed and also framed packages with tex4ht to put a frame around text

Tags: framed, mdframed, tex4ht

I googled around, and did not see something about this. I just found out that one gets an error using mdframed with tex4ht.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
text
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}

htlatex foo.tex
```

gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \end{mdframed}

?
```

The above compiles with no problem using pdflatex and with latex. So it is clearly an issue with tex4ht. Strange that it compiles ok with `latex foo.tex`, yet the error above says `Latex Error:`

Is this a known  issue? Anyone knows of a workaround? I would have to try to find alternative to mdframed since I need to compile document using pdflatex and htlatex. I just needed to put a frame around large text blocks that can contain more than
one paragraph. I am sure I will find other ways to do this that will also work with tex4ht.

Using texlive 2013, on Linux

**Update**

Text4ht also failed with packaged `framed` !

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
text

test
\end{framed}    
\end{document}

htlatex foo.tex
```

gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo.aux)
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.8 \end{framed}

?
```

May be putting frame around text with tex4ht can not be done. Will keep trying....

Comment: I don't get an error typesetting your first example, at least. (`latex foo.tex; tex4ht foo.tex`.) That said, I don't get text in a framed box either. (But I do get a usable `html` file.)

Comment: oh, the command is `htlatex foo.tex` that is the one I use. Sorry I wrote `tex4ht` there, since the tag was tex4ht. I'll correct.

Comment: Is `\fbox{\parbox{.8\textwidth}{text}}` an option? Probably one of the packages for making fancier boxes based on `\fbox` should be fine, too. That allows paragraphs (but not page breaks if that's even relevant in this case) and seems to work.

Comment: @cfr but `fbox` solution does not work. I tried that before. If you look at the HTML generated, you will see it removed the paragraph formatting. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v1uzx.png)  the above was from this file :  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2SFj.png)  so it does not really work. pdflatex produces the correct output.

Comment: I guess that's because it puts it into a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for `framed` and `mdframed` packages has been recently added to `tex4ht`, the changes will be distributed with TeXLive 2017. You can test the configuration for `mdframed` with the following configuration file, `mdframed.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{mdframed}{2}
\NewConfigure{mdframedstyle}{1}
\newcount\mdf:env:cnt
\def\mdf:id{mdframed-\the\mdf:env:cnt}
\def\mdf@trivlist#1{\global\advance\mdf:env:cnt by1\relax\a:mdframed\a:mdframedstyle}
\def\endmdf@trivlist{\b:mdframed}
 \def\mdf@lrbox#1{}
 \def\endmdf@lrbox{}

\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{%
\def\get:xcolorcss#1#2{%
   \expandafter\extractcolorspec\expandafter{#1}{\tsf:color}%
   \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf:color{HTML}\tsf:color%
   \edef#2{\#\tsf:color}%
}}{}
    \Configure{mdframed}{%
  \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="mdframed" id="\mdf:id">}\par
}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}

% use fallback macro when xcolor package haven't been loaded
\ifdefined\get:xcolorcss\else\def\get:xcolorcss#1#2{\def#2{#1}}\fi

\Configure{mdframedstyle}{%
  \get:xcolorcss{\mdf@backgroundcolor}\mdf:bgcolor
  \get:xcolorcss{\mdf@linecolor}\mdf:bordercolor
  \get:xcolorcss{\mdf@fontcolor}\mdf:fontcolor
  \def\mdf:border{\ifx\mdfl@linewidth\relax 1px\else\mdfl@linewidth\fi\space solid \mdf:bordercolor}
  \Css{\#\mdf:id{border:\mdf:border; background-color: \mdf:bgcolor; color:\mdf:fontcolor;}}
  \global\let\mdfl@linewidth\relax
}
\Hinput{mdframed}
```

This configuration redefines some internal `mdframed` macros which cause the issue and use them to insert the `HTML` code. There are two configurations, `\Configure{mdframed}` and `\Configure{mdframedstyle}`. The first one is used for `HTML` tag insertion, the second one for configuring the style. Every `mdframed` environment produces `<div>` element with unique `id`, so we can style them individually.

To illustrate that, here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

some text
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!40,linecolor=blue,linewidth=4]
  Colorized frame
\end{mdframed}
some text between
\begin{mdframed}
  Plain frame
\end{mdframed}
another instance
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!40,linecolor=blue,linewidth=4]
  Colorized frame
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following web page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\fbox` but include the text in a minipage. The following compiles Ok with tex4ht and produces the required frame around the text. The options for `minipage` can be adjusted as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}%    
\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
line 1

line 2

line 3
\end{minipage}
}     
\end{document}
```

[image]